# Private Twitter application?

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm looking to implement Twitter into an internal existing system. I need to use several features of the API (such as mentions) that require authorization.

From my understanding, this can only be used with a Twitter application, and as such I've created one.

However it all seams very public facing, asking for details like website URL, and application description, which in my case I do not need or want.

I simply need to authorize my system to make calls to the API, am I going about it the right way?

If not, is there a certain PHP library / alternative way of getting autorized? I can't imagine i'm first in this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your application going to post public tweets or is it only going to fetch timelines to display in your system?

Comment: Currently, only fetching timeline information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to provide these details so Twitter knows what kind of application you're building. If your application is not going to publish any tweets, that's entirely fine; if you're simply making GET requests, your application information won't be published anywhere.

If you don't have a public-facing URL for your application, you can enter a placeholder or a fake URL.